# Comedy movie two men find all-female society in bunker (Eastern European)

Tags: story-identification, movie

Eastern European comedy sci-fi movie probably before 2000. I saw it on TV with subtitles. I don't remember the language.

Two present day men find themselves in a future underground bunker. (Possibly they were frozen rather than time travellers?)

They discover the bunker is home to a completely female population. The MCs have to disguise themselves (badly) as women. There is some farcical stuff in a public bath with half-dressed females.

Apparently there has been some kind of nuclear war and the survivors have been stuck underground for centuries. There is some sort of periscope on the top level that reveals a dark, totally barren surface.

The survivors reproduce artificially and male babies are forbidden. Possibly men were blamed for the war.

The leader of these people is a large-built woman  who the MCs discover is

> also really a man whose gender was hidden by his mother.

These three are attacked by the women and have to flee through the hatch onto the surface where they discover that the barren horizon panorama was just a screen around the periscope. The Earth has recovered and is verdant again.

Everyone leaves the bunker for the surface where the MCs and leader will father a new society with the women.

I remember it being a very funny comedy with Benny Hill type moments mixed with political satire. Does anyone know it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexmission. This is certainly a duplicate.

Comment: @EikePierstorff That question is marked as a duplicate of yet another one. And before I even noticed your comment, I flagged this one as a duplicate of the one of which your suggestion is a duplicate. A duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate... 99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer... :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***[Sexmission](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088083/)*** (1984)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexmission):

> *Sexmission* (Polish: *Seksmisja*) is a 1984 Polish cult comedy science fiction action film. It also contains a hidden political satire layer specific to the time and place of its production.

From IMDB:

> Two scientists are placed in hibernation and should be awaken after three years. But when they wake up, it turns out that it has been fifty years, and they are the only two males in a new, underground society composed exclusively of women.

(the reveal of Her Excellency's gender)

> Later, while resting in the living room, Max and Albert suddenly hear the familiar sound of an arriving elevator and hide. It is Her Excellency who emerges from the elevator (which is hidden within a closet) to feed her caged birds. When she opens the wardrobe, she is attacked by Max who was hiding inside. During the ensuing fight, Her Excellency's breasts and hair are stripped, revealing that 'she' is a male in disguise, much to 'her' panic and Max's disgust and rage. Max also removes an electronic necklace, which was converting 'Her' Excellency's voice into one that sounds like a woman's. 'Her' Excellency tells the men his life story - just after the war, when the League of Women took power, he was 4 years old; the few boys remaining were naturalized into girls, but he was hidden by his mother. Growing up in a female disguise, he joined the League and finally was elected 'Her Excellency'. He was too afraid of women to form a relationship with any and, by revealing himself, to try to restore the old order. The government has been exaggerating the radiation level in order to keep the inhabitants underground, making them easier to control; likewise, the inhabitants are medicated to remove sexual desire. The three make a deal: Max and Albert will not compromise 'Her' Excellency's true identity, but they will stay in his home with Lamia and Emma. Later, Max and Albert, disguised as laboratory workers, add male gametes to flasks in the incubation centre. Flashing forward to several months later, a nurse, routinely wrapping newborns in blankets, is horrified to see a penis.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me adding a spoiler block containing the revelation the querent recalls.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - It's a good addition. Thank you.